# Making Comeonin's hashpwsalt() deterministic (Phoenix)

Tags: authentication, hash, elixir, phoenix-framework, bcrypt

In my Phoenix project, I am using:

```
  {:comeonin, "~> 4.0"},
  {:bcrypt_elixir, "~> 0.12.0"},
```

I see a lot of examples of user creation/authentication in which `Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(password)` is called with one argument.  However, when I run this, or `add_hash()` from `iex`, it seems like the outputs are indeterministic:

```
iex(10)> password = Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt("password")
"$2b$12$QUL1ytej8UqTvpU34E2oieshgOonf0RRZI0nva6T3HlK2RQ2JT74O"

iex(11)> password = Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt("password")
"$2b$12$jz3sb5rLrmdHVRr7Nvq0te9He0Wt00DYy4kM.t9LFp6ZSx.siovJC"

iex(12)> password = Comeonin.Bcrypt.add_hash("password")
%{password: nil,
  password_hash: "$2b$12$4Ih30p4LbNk5LQStMDtah.ht0AQSO8mhhfCUeRQlFSNuI9vEgKI/q"}

iex(13)> password = Comeonin.Bcrypt.add_hash("password")
%{password: nil,
  password_hash: "$2b$12$92oe9Ccovrwi1GuHK5Zo3uaxbQEXEvgyqEx6o4tsW2J8TEsc/LrtS"}
```

Why does this occur, and how can I guarantee a deterministic hash from a given input?

Comment: Because the returned value contains a salt along with the hashed value and the salt is random. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918460/why-is-the-hash-generated-by-bcrypt-non-deterministic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hashpwsalt` generates a random salt each time, so the resulting hash is going to be different every time. This is the recommended way of generating a password hash. You then use [check_pass](https://hexdocs.pm/comeonin/Comeonin.Bcrypt.html#check_pass/3) or [checkpw](https://hexdocs.pm/comeonin/Comeonin.Bcrypt.html#checkpw/2) for checking if a password matches the stored hash. If for some reason you want to get the same hash, you can use the library directly. For an example, see here:

https://github.com/riverrun/bcrypt_elixir/blob/master/lib/bcrypt.ex#L84

Can't think of a reason you would want to do this, though. It's more likely that you're making a mistake.

Comment: Thanks.  I definitely overthought this.